# SQL Query not Checking After and Clause

Tags: sql

I need to find the student id(s) and names(s) of all students enrolled in CS348 **and either in ECE264 or in CS503**. However my query only returns the students that are in CS348.

```
select distinct STUDENT.s_id, STUDENT.s_name
from STUDENT
join ENROLMENT on STUDENT.s_id=ENROLMENT.s_id
where ENROLMENT.c_id = 'CS348' 
  and STUDENT.s_id = (select distinct STUDENT.s_id
                      from ENROLMENT
                      where ENROLMENT.c_id in ('ECE264', 'CS503'));
```

Here's a look at the database:

```
STUDENT

s_id s_name

234  Anglo Anebal         F
235  Abram Ace            S
236  Adelbert Antti       SP  
237  William Walker       GR
238  Emila Wdyth          GR
239  Judith Elba          S
240  Benjamin Bratt       SP
241  Tawny Kitaen         F 

ENROLMENT

c_name    s_id

CS110     240
CS110     241
CS348     235
CS348     239
CS348     237
CS250     236
CS250     241 
ECE264    236
ECE264    237
ECE264    238
MA525     236
CS503     238
CS503     239
CS448     240
CS250     240
MA511     240
```

Comment: I removed the conflicting database tags. Please tag only the database you are really using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to find the student id(s) and names(s) of all students enrolled in CS348 and either in ECE264 or in CS503.

Your approach is basically fine except for the `=` with the subquery:

```
select s.s_id, s.s_name
from STUDENT s join
     ENROLMENT
     on s.s_id = e.s_id
where e.c_id = 'CS348' and
      s.s_id in (select s.s_id
                 from ENROLMENT e2
                 where e2.c_id in ('ECE264', 'CS503')
                );
```

Note the use of table aliases to simplify the writing of the query.  Also, `select distinct` is definitely not needed in the subquery.  And I doubt it is needed in the outer query as well -- a student probably cannot enroll in a class more than once.

That said, I often approach this type of problem using aggregation:

```
select s.s_id, s.s_name
from STUDENT s join
     ENROLMENT
     on s.s_id = e.s_id
group by s.s_id, s.s_name
having sum(case when e.c_id = 'CS348' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when e.c_id in ('ECE264', 'CS503') then 1 else 0 end) > 0 ;
```

Each of the `having` conditions is checking one of the conditions on your courses.

Comment: Such a clever way to do it, easy to understand, yet I would have never thought about it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Your query is a bit convoluted and can be simplified to

```
select distinct STUDENT.s_id, STUDENT.s_name
from STUDENT
join ENROLMENT on STUDENT.s_id=ENROLMENT.s_id
where ENROLMENT.c_id = 'CS348' and ENROLMENT.c_id in ('ECE264', 'CS503');
```

The first sentence and second sentence do not seem to completely agree with each other on what you want. The first sentence matches the query. The second sentence suggests that what you actually want is "enrolled in CS348 **OR** either in ECE264 or in CS503"

```
select distinct STUDENT.s_id, STUDENT.s_name
from STUDENT
join ENROLMENT on STUDENT.s_id=ENROLMENT.s_id
where ENROLMENT.c_id in ('CS348', 'ECE264', 'CS503');
```